# Google App Engine: Web XML not handled the same way online or offline

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

I got the web.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

        <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SellVideo</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>WEB-INF/jsp/sell-video.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SellVideo</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/sell-video</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Edit</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>vidaao.EditServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Request</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>vidaao.RequestServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Upload</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>vidaao.UploadServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Serve</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>vidaao.ServeServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Guestbook</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>vidaao.GuestbookServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Profile</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>vidaao.ProfileServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>vidaao.RegisterServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Vidaao</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>vidaao.VidaaoServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Connect</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>vidaao.ConnectServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Ajax</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>vidaao.AjaxServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Ajax</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ajax</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Connect</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/connect</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Edit</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/edit</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/register</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Request</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/request</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Upload</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/upload</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Serve</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/serve</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Guestbook</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/guestbook</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Profile</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>services</param-name>
   <param-value/>
  </init-param>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The sevlet Profile should math all url like this wwww.xxx.com/* if a url mapping wasn't match before.

The profile is that offine it is working fine but when i try to deploy everything is going into the profile servlet directly. For example sell-video or even sell-video.jsp is redirect to the profile servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it,

I have to add a slash in front of WEB-INF,

like this : `<jsp-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/sell-video.jsp</jsp-file>`

Still weird that the problem only append online and not on the dev side, make it harder to debug.